# How can I set timer with a delay larger than 2147283648(2^31)?

Tags: actionscript-3

When I set timer delay with a number larger than 2^31, the timer trigger the event immediately.Why did this happen? I saw the API reference that the delay is number type, so it can deal with numbers larger than 2^31.

How can I solve the problem?

```
    var cou: Number = diff - now.getTime()
    var timer: Timer = new Timer(cou, 1);
    trace(cou + " timer delay " + timer.delay)
     add(misbox, new Date(diff) + " " + para);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, te1);
    timer.start();

    function te1(event: Event): void {
      trace(new Date(diff) + " " + para);
    }
```

The quote from API reference:

Timer   ()  Constructor
public function Timer(delay:Number, repeatCount:int = 0)

Language Version:   ActionScript 3.0
Runtime Versions:   AIR 1.0, Flash Player 9, Flash Lite 4

Constructs a new Timer object with the specified delay and repeatCount states.

The timer does not start automatically; you must call the start() method to start it.

Parameters
    delay:Number — The delay between timer events, in milliseconds. A delay lower than 20 milliseconds is not recommended. Timer frequency is limited to 60 frames per second, meaning a delay lower than 16.6 milliseconds causes runtime problems.

repeatCount:int (default = 0) — Specifies the number of repetitions. If zero, the timer repeats indefinitely, up to a **maximum of 24.86 days** (int.MAX_VALUE + 1). If nonzero, the timer runs the specified number of times and then stops.

i think the timer will trigger immediately if the event will happen on the day after 24.86 days.

how can i trigger a event after the 24.86 days?

Comment: By all means, do you expect your flash app to run for straight 2.1m seconds? The timer won't save the state if your app is re-run.

Comment: Timer should not be used for that and certainly not that way, use the Date class.

Comment: @Vesper, in fact i want to run the app for as long as possible

Comment: @BotMaster , i want to do some action every day, but the interval between each action is irregular. how can trigger a event by using Date class?

Comment: You can compare 2 date instances and you do that by running a timer each n milliseconds. In that timer listener you compare your Date class instances. It is the right way to go. A Date instance can store any date even a Date that is years in the future and you can check those Date easily but you can't set a timer to trigger years in the future, it won't work.

Comment: @botmaster , the problem is the timer will stop after 24.86 days. how can i trigger some event after 24.86 days? maybe i can start another timer when the first timer stop. but this would be very trouble

Comment: Then don't use a Timer, an enterframe event will do just fine. I've made a calendar system with alarms using Date and enterframe that works just fine whether it's set for next day or the next 20 years it works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Set the delay as compound, setting both `delay` and `count` values in `Timer` constructor, this way you can set up to (2^31)^2, and then listen for [`flash.events.TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#event:timerComplete) to trigger your delayed function.

If you are unable to factorize the desired delay into two numbers of 2^31-1 or less, select the numbers to have a compound as close to the desired delay as possible.

An example:

```
var cou:Number = diff-now.getTime();
var td:int;
var tc:int;
if (cou<2147483647) { td=Math.floor(cou); tc=1; }
else {
   // stupid, do a square root and use its floor as both td and tc
   td=Math.floor(Math.sqrt(cou));
   tc=td;
}
var timer: Timer = new Timer(td, tc);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, te1);
timer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your timer for 2^31, when it gets to 2^31, increment a second variable by 1, when the timer gets to 2^31 again, increment the second variable by one, do this until enough time passes and then do your action.